# Multiple command for one test run via maven cmd

Tags: java, maven, junit

Can you explain, please, how I can run a specific TestSuite using maven with rerunFailingTestCount? When I use

```
mvn -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestCount=2 test
```

it works fine for me, but it runs every test in my project. Then I've created TestSuites and invoke using

```
mvn -Dtest=TestSuiteName test
```

and it also works fine. But is there any way to combine both commands to run specific TestSuite with rerunFailingTestCount feature?

Comment: I found solution:

`mvn -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestCount=2 test`

Thanks to @Michael for editing my question.

Comment: Isn't that the same command you said that you'd already tried?

Comment: oh, worng copy/paste. Thank you one more time!
Right command is simply combination of 2 comands: 
`mvn -Dtest=TestSuiteName -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2 test`

Comment: You're allowed to post an answer to your own question, so that others may benefit from it later. You should do that :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to my problem:

```
mvn -Dtest=TestSuiteName -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2 test
```

This command will run specific TestSuite with rerunFailingTestsCount parameter.